# How to use ffmpeg.dmg on Mac same way as ffmpeg.exe on windows via bat files?

Tags: windows, macos, batch-file, ffmpeg

I was wondering how can I use ffmpeg.dmg on Mac same way as ffmpeg.exe on windows via bat files? without installing ffmpeg on the PC.

For example if I wanted to create a thumbnial from video file I type this line in a text file and rename it to xxxx.bat and place it beside the exe

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "input.mp4" -an -ss 00:00:02 -an -r 1 -vframes 1 -s 512x512 -y "output.jpg"
```

anyway to do the same on mac? I tried renaming ffmpeg.exe to ffmpeg.dmg and xxxx.bat to xxxx.command thought it was that simple :) but of course didn't work.

Comment: As you probably figured out I have no clue how Mac works so I don't know if that's even possible.. Thank Youm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download compiled binaries of `ffmpeg` for Mac as well [here](http://www.ffmpegmac.net/).

For the batch-thingy you can find more information [over here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2778315?start=0&tstart=0) as it needs more than typing and a double click in Mac appearentely.

Comment: The compiled binaries helped, but still not quite there..

Comment: What does "still not quite there" mean? Your question basically was how to get ffmpeg to mac and how to change a batch-file to a command-file for mac. Up there are the answers. What is missing, wrong or not working?

Comment: my line now is
[open ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -an -ss 00:00:02 -an -r 1 -vframes 1 -s 512x512 -y "output.jpg"]

but it returns invalid option --i

Comment: Try to do something like `ffmpeg /?` or `--?` or `-?` or leave it out at all in the first place to have a look what options are available. I have no clue of mac either, but you should start research on your own!

Comment: Trying :/ mac apparently is so frustrating